# Aurelia, installation issue with webpack

Tags: installation, webpack, aurelia

I wanted to try Aurelia today but I have an issue with the webpack skeleton. 
So, I have downloaded the webpack skeleton on the official website, and I started the npm install and start script.

But when I browse to http://localhost:9000/ I have a lot of errors.

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined

  - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:37 handleExternals
    [aurelia]/[config-generate-index-html]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPl    ugin.js:37:33

  - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:46 next
    [aurelia]/[config-generate-index-html]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPl    ugin.js:46:8

  - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:59 handleExternals
    [aurelia]/[config-generate-index-html]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPl    ugin.js:59:7

  - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:79 ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.
    [aurelia]/[config-generate-index-html]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPl    ugin.js:79:5

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:177 
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:177:3

  - Tapable.js:123 NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:123:70

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:161 NormalModuleFactory.create
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:161:8

  - Compilation.js:356 Compilation.process [as _addModuleChain]
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:356:16

  - Compilation.js:427 Compilation.process [as addEntry]
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:427:7

  - SingleEntryPlugin.js:22 SingleEntryPlugin.
    [aurelia]/[config-generate-index-html]/[webpack]/lib/SingleEntryPlugin.js:22    :15

  - Tapable.js:156 Compiler.applyPluginsParallel
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:156:14

  - Compiler.js:431 Compiler.compile
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:431:7

  - Compiler.js:237 Compiler.runAsChild
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:237:7

  - compiler.js:70 
    [aurelia]/[config-generate-index-html]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js    :70:19

  - compiler.js:69 Object.compileTemplate
    [aurelia]/[config-generate-index-html]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js    :69:10

  - index.js:47 Compiler.
    [aurelia]/[config-generate-index-html]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:47:40

  - Tapable.js:156 Compiler.applyPluginsParallel
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:156:14

  - Compiler.js:431 Compiler.compile
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:431:7

  - Compiler.js:47 Watching.
    [aurelia]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:47:17
```

I use 2.15.9 npm version and 4.5.0 node version.

Comment: your npm version must be > 3. Try `npm install npm -g` then download the skeleton again

Comment: @FabioLuz would you mind posting this as an answer. I'll give you an upvote!

Comment: @AshleyGrant sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your npm version must be 3 or greater. Update npm using `npm install npm -g` then install the packages again.

Comment: Nice, thank you.
Maybe this information should appear in the documentation ? @AshleyGrant ?